# Ripple behaves strangely when using layout_weight

Tags: android

I'm working on a **widget** that requires me to evenly space some elements in a group. I achieve this by using `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_weight="1"` applied to all elements, as so:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget_skip_prev"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ui_unbounded_ripple"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget_play_pause"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ui_unbounded_ripple" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget_skip_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ui_unbounded_ripple" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The drawable I use at the background is this, which provides a fixed ripple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
    android:radius="24dp" />
```

The problem is that when I use the ripple with `layout_weight=1` the ripple will start from it's largest state and then shrink, instead of starting small and growing like it normally should. I've attached a video of what it looks like below:

[image: Strange ripple behavior]

Removing the `layout_weight` attribute solves this problem, but I need it to get the UI result I want. I cannot use any other layouts than the ones `RemoteView` allows, so `ConstraintLayout` isn't an option. Is there anything I can do here?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget_skip_prev"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget_play_pause"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/widget_skip_next"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This solves the issue, but is there a way to limit it's size? The ripples end up expanding far beyond the what I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

put in your each ImageButton

```
 android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```